# Scrollview touch event in Corona SDK?

Tags: coronasdk

I have scrollview widget with one child (myrect)

I want to detect the touch ended event for "myrect" however currently it only detects the "began" phase !!

here is the complete code

```
 --main.lua
 local widget = require "widget"

 local myscrollview = widget.newScrollView{}

 local myrect = display.newRect(0, 0, display.contentWidth, 68)                  
 myrect:setFillColor(255,100,100,255)
 myscrollview:insert(myrect)

 local function ontouch(event)

    if event.phase == "ended" then
            print("event ended")
    end
end
myrect:addEventListener( "touch", ontouch )
```

what I need is a basic functionality it is strange that corona does not support that or maybe I am missing something

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you SatheeshJM your code for some how give me wrong result so when I click anywhere outside the rect the "touch ended event " will be fired

but finally I have the solution Just in case if anyone is interested

here is the enhanced version of the solution

Thanks to Danny http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2012/05/15/scrollview-problem

and Jonathan Beebe for this helpful workaround https://gist.github.com/1590908

```
local widget = require "widget"

local myscrollview = widget.newScrollView{}

local myrect = display.newRect(0, 0, display.contentWidth, 68)                  
myrect:setFillColor(255,100,100,255)
myscrollview:insert(myrect)

local function ontouch(event)

    if event.phase == "moved" then
        local dx = math.abs( event.x - event.xStart )
        local dy = math.abs( event.y - event.yStart )

        if dx > 5 or dy > 5 then
            myscrollview:takeFocus( event )
        end
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
    display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)
            print("event ended")
    end

    return true
end
myrect:addEventListener( "touch", ontouch )
```

Answer (score 2):

When you touch the rectangle, a touch event with phase "began" is fired.

Since the scrollview has been inserted into the scrollview, the touch event is propogated to the scrollview.  So now, your scrollview receives the "began" event and the corresponding "moved" and "ended" phases.  The rectangle receives no more touch events.

If you REALLY want to detect the "ended" phase, you can do this

```
 local function ontouch(event)
        if event.phase == "began" then 
            return true
        elseif event.phase == "ended" then
            print("event ended")
        end
  end
```

But there is a catch.  The scrollview won't work, if you scroll it by pressing on the rectangle. You will have to scroll by pressing on an empty space in the scrollview.

Hope that made sense!

EDIT:

Ok, There is actually a way! You pass the event focus back to the rectangle object, from the scrollview listener.

```
 --main.lua
 local widget = require "widget"
 local myrect

 local function scrollviewListener(event)
    display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(myrect)
 end 
 local myscrollview = widget.newScrollView{listener = scrollviewListener}


 myrect = display.newRect(0, 0, display.contentWidth, 68)                  
 myrect:setFillColor(255,100,100,255)
 myscrollview:insert(myrect)


 local function ontouch(event)

    if event.phase == "ended" then
            print("event ended")
    end
end
myrect:addEventListener( "touch", ontouch )
```